# Eclipse RCP - adding properties to exising Project in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Greetings fellow Stackoverflownians,

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, and within it is also the standard `Project Explorer View`.

I need to add several properties to a `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project` to be presented alongside the usual `Resource` properties in the standard `Properties View`.

My thought process was that I add another listener to the `SelectionService`:

```
window =PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
window.getSelectionService().addSelectionListener("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer", listener);
```

and in this selection listener I get the selected Project, alter it, and pass it forward to the selection service.

Trouble is, I don't have any method to set the selection programatically without a content provider.

Also, as far as I see, `Project` doesn't implement `IPropertySource`, hence it would be rather difficult to subclass it, overwrite the `getPropertyDescriptors/Values` methods...

If so, how do I get the content provider of the `Project Explorer` view?

Or how can I set the selection within the `SelectionService`?

Any help/opinions appreciated!

Comment: The `IPropertySource` for `IProject` is done using an `IAdapterFactory` (for some views this will be `StandardPropertiesAdapterFactory`). The actual source class being `ResourcePropertySource`.

Comment: Alright, so how would you go about it? How can one set the property descriptors and values through that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded in adding a property to an existing `IProject`, despite it not implementing `IPropertySource` (and hence would've been able to just add some functionality by subclassing and overwriting the `getPropertyDescriptors` and `getPropertyValue` methods.

Thanks to greg-449 I was able to understand the `StandardPropertiesAdapterFactory` functionality that made a `ResourcePropertySource` from the `IProject` (that extends `IResource`)

So a way to work around all this is that you use a subclass of `AdvancedPropertySection` to display the `IProject`'s properties...

Here's the kewd:

I link the `ProjectExplorer`'s view ID with a `TabDescriptorProvider` in `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyContributor">
      <propertyContributor
            contributorId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"
            tabDescriptorProvider="eb.tresos.bustools.connection.extraproperty.TabDescriptorProvider">
         <propertyCategory
               category="tabbedCategory">
         </propertyCategory>
      </propertyContributor>
   </extension>
```

After that, we define the `TabDescriptorProvider`, and link it to our custom `AdvancedPropertySection`:

```
public class TabDescriptorProvider implements ITabDescriptorProvider {

    @Override
    public ITabDescriptor[] getTabDescriptors( IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection ) {
        AbstractTabDescriptor[] tabs = new AbstractTabDescriptor[1];
        tabs[0] = new TabDescriptor("Aww shucks, TabDescriptorTitle");

        return tabs;
    }

    class TabDescriptor extends AbstractTabDescriptor {
        String label;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param label sets the label text of the tab
         */
        TabDescriptor( String label ) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public List getSectionDescriptors() {
            List<SectionDescriptor> sList = new ArrayList<SectionDescriptor>();
            sList.add( new SectionDescriptor( label ) );

            return sList;
        }

        @Override
        public String getCategory() {
            //Stub
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            //stub
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public String getLabel() {
            return "Resource";
        }
    }

    class SectionDescriptor extends AbstractSectionDescriptor {

        String section;
        List<AbstractPropertySection> sectionTabs = new ArrayList<AbstractPropertySection>();

        public SectionDescriptor( String section ) {
            this.section = section;

        }

        /**
         * SectionId
         */
        @Override
        public String getId() {
            //stub
            return "";
        }

        /**
         * SectionClass
         */
        @Override
        public ISection getSectionClass() {
            return new AuxiliaryProjectSection();
        }

        /**
         * SectionTab
         */
        @Override
        public String getTargetTab() {
            //stub
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

And the `Section` itself:

```
public class AuxiliaryProjectSection extends AdvancedPropertySection {
    @Override
    public void setInput(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        if (selection instanceof StructuredSelection) {
            Object firstElement = ((StructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();
            if (firstElement instanceof IProject) {
                final IProject theProject = (IProject) firstElement;
                ISelection selection2 = new StructuredSelection(new ResourcePropertySource(theProject) {

                    @Override
                    public IPropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
                        ArrayList<IPropertyDescriptor>  arrayList = new ArrayList<IPropertyDescriptor>();
                        IPropertyDescriptor[] array = {new PropertyDescriptor("ID-ul", "Labelul")};
                        arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(super.getPropertyDescriptors()));
                        arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
                        return arrayList.toArray(new IPropertyDescriptor[0]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getPropertyValue(Object id) {
                        if (id.equals("ID-ul"))
                            return "Silly Value";
                        else
                            return super.getPropertyValue(id);
                    }

                });
                super.setInput(part, selection2); 
            } else {
                super.setInput(part, selection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again, Greg!

Comment: If you're going to downvote, offer complete criticism via a comment, please.